# android ndk compilation error seekdir,endian-ness functions

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am compiling a code using ndk-r10 which is using these methods : 
`seekdir(p,0)` but giving error  For All ABIs : armeabi,armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64.

```
File Included for this : #include <dirent.h>
```

Endian Ness Functions :

```
be16toh() - Giving error for armeabi-v7a,x86
le16toh()- Giving  error for armeabi-v7a,x86


File Included for this :  #include <endian.h>
```

Are these methods portable.

```
Error is : Undefined reference to <method name>
```

Also the included files doesn't seem to have the definitions for these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[seekdir()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/iio/Documentation/iio_utils.h) is not implemented for Android Bionic libc for x86.The alternate way to use it is 
+closedir(dp)
+dp = opendir(scan_el_dir);

This compiles and test fine by android-ndk.